# How could I hide the overflow of my animated circle ripple effect?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to get a ripple effect on the bottom left corner. What I would like to see is the ripple effect to only show in the hero area (100% of the retina) and not to overflow into the other section.

I thought I could hide it with 'overflow: hidden' but I seem to be wrong about this.

I'm hoping this explanation of what I want is clear. Let me know if I wasn't.

New to frontend dev

```css
.hero-body {
  background: #3399ff;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 50% 0 0;
  background: white;
  animation: ripple 15s infinite;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #508fb9;
}

.small {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: -100px;
  bottom: -100px;
}

.medium {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  left: -200px;
  bottom: -200px;
}

.large {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  left: -300px;
  bottom: -300px;
}

.xlarge {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  left: -400px;
  bottom: -400px;
}

.xxlarge {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  left: -500px;
  bottom: -500px;
}

.shade1 {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.shade2 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.shade3 {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.shade4 {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.shade5 {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class='ripple-background'>
    <div class='circle xxlarge shade1'></div>
    <div class='circle xlarge shade2'></div>
    <div class='circle large shade3'></div>
    <div class='circle mediun shade4'></div>
    <div class='circle small shade5'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use     `position: fixed;`

```css
body {
    background: #3399ff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 50% 0 0;
  background: white;
  animation: ripple 15s infinite;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #508fb9;
}

.small {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: -100px;
  bottom: -100px;
}

.medium {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  left: -200px;
  bottom: -200px;
}

.large {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  left: -300px;
  bottom: -300px;
}

.xlarge {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  left: -400px;
  bottom: -400px;
}

.xxlarge {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  left: -500px;
  bottom: -500px;
}

.shade1 {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.shade2 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.shade3 {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.shade4 {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.shade5 {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class='ripple-background'>
    <div class='circle xxlarge shade1'></div>
    <div class='circle xlarge shade2'></div>
    <div class='circle large shade3'></div>
    <div class='circle mediun shade4'></div>
    <div class='circle small shade5'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```